# MatPaginator - Get events when start / end loading page data

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it posible to know when the MatPaginator has finish loading the page?

when loading a page with 500 items my browser freeze for few seconds, so i'd like to show
loading... until the page is fully loaded
handlePage($event) only fires when paging

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100,500]"
showFirstLastButtons
(page)="handlePage($event)"

> 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mat-spinner` for that along with some basic logic.

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
  <mat-progress-spinner color="primary" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
</div>
```

and then in your ts file where your data is being fetched you can use:

```
isLoading = true;

this.yourService.getTableData().subscribe(data => {
   this.dataSource = data
   this.isLoading = false;
   }, 
   error => this.isLoading = false
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure this is the answer, I need to know when the paging starts, and when the browser finished loading all the page items in the table.
hope you understand me :)